# sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK) what does it return in multicore processor?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

in case of multiple cpu's (in mu ubuntu 14.04 desktop the system monitor display 4 cpu's  "double core I5 laptop") the sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK)  return 100. for every second the system has 100 _SC_CLK_TCK  available to all the process OR 100x4(the numbers of CPU)?

Answer (score 0):

No, from system clock perspective each CPU operates independently. So number of cores, CPUs or hardware threads is not affecting it.

Comment: The total numbers of CLK_TCK in the system for one second is 100 or 400? I need to run 90.000 process in 10  wall clock time hours. The average  CLK_TCK  of these precess is 150 CLK_TCK. In 10 h The total CLK_TCK is 3600 x 10h x 100CLK_TCK/sec x 4 (=Number of CPUS)? OR 3600 x 10h x 100CLK_TCK/sec?

Comment: @user1675224 Please explain why do you try to measure/calculate number of ticks? Process lifetime is not bound to system ticks, it depends on own process behavior and system scheduler decisions (which could use high-resolution timers).

Comment: The process lives 10-20 min (wall clock time) and it needs 150 CLK_TCK. In order to run 90.000  process in 10 wall clock hours, I will run  ~ 1200  process parallel.

Comment: CLK_TCK is just a constant, you process shouldn't need that. For example, you do not need _g_ (9.8 meters per second), you need _gravity_ to walk on Moon. What your is process really need? Some event which happens only on timer tick?

Comment: I need this information in order to figure out how many process my system are able to run in 10 wall clock hours. I am making a feasibility study for one project. So in one case the system is able to run 4x more jobs... I want to know this information in order to calculate the number of servers which my boss has to provide  in the dedicated cluster... In the production the load will be 50 times bigger...

Comment: Than answer is yes: the more processors system have the more processes could be run in parallel (if they able to do so). However if at the moment more than 4 processes are ready to run, system _scheduler_ tries to satisfy needs of processes. So it will allocate a _timeslice_ for each process, and after process uses _timeslice_ it will take processor from it and give to another process (that is called _context switch_).